# Web Essentials for VS2013 Update 3 is extremely laggy

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I updated VS2013 to Update 3 along with Web Essentials.  This is my only extension.  Now, when I run a solution, it freezes for ~3 seconds every ~5 seconds, making VS totally unusable when I'm debugging.  I can't edit any source.  Is anyone else experiencing this that has found a fix?  My only solution is uninstalling WE.

Comment: Yes, I had to disable it as well.

Comment: Check that all of the "compile on build" options are turned off in Tools : Options : Web Essentials.